# Awk code with associative arrays -- array doesn't seem populated, but no error

Tags: awk, associative-array

1. Question: Why does it seem that date_list[d] and isin_list[i] are not getting populated, in the code segment below?
2. AWK Code (on GNU-AWK on a Win-7 machine)

   ```
   BEGIN { FS = "," } # This SEBI  data set has comma-separated fields (NSE snapshots are pipe-separated)

   # UPDATE the lists for DATE ($10), firm_ISIN ($9), EXCHANGE ($12), and FII_ID ($5).
   ( $17~/_EQ\>/ )    {
       if (date[$10]++ == 0) date_list[d++] = $10;   # Dates appear in order in raw data
       if (isin[$9]++ == 0) isin_list[i++] = $9;     # ISINs appear out of order in raw data
       print $10, date[$10], $9, isin[$9], date_list[d], d, isin_list[i], i 
   }
   ```
3. input data

   ```
   49290,C198962542782200306,6/30/2003,433581,F5811773991200306,S5405611832200306,B5086397478200306,NESTLE INDIA LTD.,INE239A01016,6/27/2003,1,E9035083824200306,REG_DL_STLD_02,591.13,5655,3342840.15,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
   49291,C198962542782200306,6/30/2003,433563,F6292896459200306,S6344227311200306,B6110521493200306,GRASIM INDUSTRIES LTD.,INE047A01013,6/27/2003,1,E9035083824200306,REG_DL_STLD_02,495.33,3700,1832721,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
   49292,C198962542782200306,6/30/2003,433681,F6513202607200306,S1724027402200306,B6372023178200306,HDFC BANK LTD,INE040A01018,6/26/2003,1,E745964372424200306,REG_DL_STLD_02,242,2600,629200,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_D,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
   49293,C7885768925200306,6/30/2003,48128,F4406661052200306,S7376401565200306,B4576522576200306,Maruti Udyog Limited,INE585B01010,6/28/2003,3,E912851176274200306,REG_DL_STLD_04,125,44600,5575000,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
   49294,C7885768925200306,6/30/2003,48129,F4500260787200306,S1312094035200306,B4576522576200306,Maruti Udyog Limited,INE585B01010,6/28/2003,4,E912851176274200306,REG_DL_STLD_04,125,445600,55700000,REG_DL_INSTR_EQ,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
   49295,C7885768925200306,6/30/2003,48130,F6425024637200306,S2872499118200306,B4576522576200306,Maruti Udyog Limited,INE585B01010,6/28/2003,3,E912851176274200306,REG_DL_STLD_04,125,48000,6000000,REG_DL_INSTR_EU,REG_DL_DLAY_P,DL_RPT_TYPE_N,DL_AMDMNT_DEL_00
   ```
4. output that I am getting

   ```
   6/27/2003 1 INE239A01016 1  1  1
   6/27/2003 2 INE047A01013 1  1  2
   6/26/2003 1 INE040A01018 1  2  3
   6/28/2003 1 INE585B01010 1  3  4
   6/28/2003 2 INE585B01010 2  3  4
   ```
5. Expected output

   As far as I can tell, the print is printing out correctly (i) $10 (the date) (ii) date[$10), the count for each date (iii) $9 (firm-ID called ISIN) (iv) isin[$9], the count for each ISIN (v) d (index of date_list, the number of unique dates) and (vi) i (index of isin_list, the number of unique ISINs). I should also get two more columns -- columns 5 and 7 below -- for date_list[d] and isin_list[i], which will have values that look like $10 and $9.

   ```
   6/27/2003 1 INE239A01016 1  6/27/2003 1 INE239A01016  1
   6/27/2003 2 INE047A01013 1  6/27/2003 1 INE047A01013  2
   6/26/2003 1 INE040A01018 1  6/26/2003 2 INE040A01018  3
   6/28/2003 1 INE585B01010 1  6/28/2003 3 INE585B01010  4
   6/28/2003 2 INE585B01010 2  6/28/2003 3 INE585B01010  4
   ```

Comment: you're missing data in your `expected output` section? That would be helpful. Also learn to use the formatting tool `{}` at the top left of the edit box. Highlight a block that should keep its original format with your mouse, and then click `{}`.

Comment: That said, I'm guessing that you're using `if (date[$10]++ == 0)` (and similar) to determine if a value is already in an array or not. The std solution in `awk` for that task is written like `if(!($10 in date)) { date[$10]++; date_list[d++]=$10 }` Good luck.

Comment: `date_list[d]` and `isin_list[i]` are accessing one past the elements you just stored. Try `date_list[d-1]` and `isin_list[i-1]`.

Comment: This does not increment the date[$10]++ counter if it's already 1. I need both a counter for each date, and d, which tells me the number of unique dates. What puzzles me is that the old code (or something almost exactly like it, also on SO archives) worked fine. Hard disk died, re-installed, etc. Thought I was OK, but this old example no longer works.

Comment: [d-1] and [i-1] instead of [d] and [i] did it. Get expected output. Thanks. @ooga. Only am unclear why the old example worked.

Comment: Comparing the solution to the old code which worked, I think my mistake was that this time the print was just a clause in a bigger statement. The last time I computed values in the arrays in EXACTLY the same way, but the print was done only in the END, and the suggestion given then by @jonathan.leffler had in the print loop test-counter used "<" and not "<=" which I realize now exactly matches your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Murgie, Please post your solution as an answer and you can accept it. As it stands, this question is ripe for closure.

Comment: The actual code I now use is {    if (date[$10]++ == 0) date_list[d++] = $10;                 
                                     if (isin[$9]++ == 0) isin_list[i++] = $9;                   }  ( $11~/1|2|3|5|9|1[24]/ )) {{ ++BNR[$10,$9,$12,$5]}

Answer (score 0):

actual code I now use is

```
{    if (date[$10]++ == 0) date_list[d++] = $10;                 
     if (isin[$9]++ == 0) isin_list[i++] = $9;}        
( $11~/1|2|3|5|9|1[24]/ )) { ++BNR[$10,$9,$12,$5]}         
END { { for (u = 0; u < d; u++)  
      {for (v = 0; v < i; v++) 
      {    if  (BNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v]]>0) 
               BR=BNR[date_list[u],isin_list[v]] 
              { print(date_list[u], isin_list[v], BR}}}}}
```

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: Is this the solution or an update on the question? If it is the first, mark as accepted so that it is clear for future readers; if it is the later, add it to your question.